# plot image with interpolation in Python Bokeh like matplotlib?

Tags: python, image, plot, interpolation, bokeh

Is there any way to plot 2D array as an image using Bokeh with interpolation like in Matplotlib? I am able to plot using an example: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/image.html
However, the image is to coarse. I like the way interpolation work in Matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html

I tried to perform interpolation beforehand but the matrix size now is to big.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I've found the answer in pyviz's Gitter.
The solution combines `Holoviews` and `Datashader`:

```
import holoviews as hv 
from holoviews import opts
from holoviews.operation.datashader import regrid

img = hv.Image(data)
regrid(img, upsample=True, interpolation='bilinear')
```

Comment: Thank you. Great for viewing seismic. Is the code you posted [here](https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/distinct-holoviews-plots-sharing-the-same-data-range-when-embedded-in-panel-dashboards/242) part of an open-source package?

Comment: hey @skytaker, you can find it [here](https://gitlab.com/hsansilva/seismic_with_holoviews)

Answer (score 0):

If you are [working with a large dataset](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Large_Data.html) then you could try Bokeh in combination with Datashader/HoloViews like in [this example](http://datashader.org/dashboard.html). When zooming in, Datashader can dynamically create new high quality images from your data that could be displayed in your Bokeh plot.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I implemented dynspread and datashader like this: bounds=(0,0,2,2)
shadeable = [hv.Image(img, bounds=bounds).redim.range(z=(-20, 20))]
z = hv.Layout([dynspread(datashade(e.relabel(e.__class__.name),cmap=cmap)) for e in shadeable])
z.opts(opts.Image(height=900, width=600,title='Image'))
fig = hv.render(z)
show(fig)
Somehow, the quality of image is now degraded. May be I have to implement interpolation using tf?

Comment: Sorry, I primarily use Bokeh and don't have much experience with `HoloView`. What I meant is that you could implement a Python callback linked to your `WheelZoomTool` so when you zoom in a new image is generated by `Datashader`. Like the callback passed to DynamicMap() in the second Datashader link from my answer and also consult HoloView/Bokeh documentation how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but an observation - I've noticed that plotting an image via an image_url source it appears interpolated when zoomed in whilst if you read in the same image and display it from a columndatasource via 'image' it then appears blocky when zoomed. I'd love to know how to make it appear interpolated too when zoomed, eg like the raw png image appears. Holoview/datashader would be a great solution but in my case I need it to work offline/as a standalone html file.