# HoloViews create interpolated colorful heatmap

Tags: python, bokeh, heatmap, holoviews

I have created a heatmap using holoviews on top of bokeh

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10) * 100)
heatmap = hv.HeatMap((df.columns, df.index, df))
heatmap.opts(width=500, title='Thermal map', colorbar=True, tools=['hover'], cmap='Turbo')
```

and got the following heatmap:

[image]

How can I make the heatmap color interpolate same as the colorbar

Like moving from pixel to pixel as a gradient

similar to:

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: The [docs](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/HeatMap.html) refer to `For full documentation and the available style and plot options, use hv.help(hv.HeatMap)`. Maybe you can try that and look for something like "bilinear interpolation"?

Comment: You could also have a look at hv.QuadMesh() for this: https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/QuadMesh.html

Comment: HeatMap (as currently implemented) is for categorical axes, where interpolation isn't meaningful. Image or QuadMesh would be appropriate for continuous axes, but even in those cases, I don't think Bokeh offers any support for interpolation directly, but there are workarounds like https://stackoverflow.com/a/59458256/5909839 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on post comments I was able to interpolate heatmap, especially James A. Bednar comment.

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
from holoviews.operation.datashader import regrid
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10) * 100)
img = hv.Image((df.columns, df.index, df))
img.opts(width=500, height=500, title='Thermal map', cmap='RdYlBu_r' ,tools['hover'], colorbar=True)
inter_img = regrid(img, upsample=True, interpolation='bilinear')
img + inter_img
```

[image]

Thanks so much